# How to restrict keyof T to number fields? where T[keyof T] is number

Tags: typescript

I want to restrict field parameter in following function:

```
function sum<T>(source: T[], field: keyof T) {
   for(const item of source) {

   }
}
```

so that `item[field]` is always a number..

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Additionally, how to restring non generic function parameter:

function foo(field: keyof MyObj){
}

so that

```
interface MyObj { name: string, value: number; }
foo("name"); // throws compiler error
```

Comment: If `item[field]` is always a number, then `source` is a `[]number`, hence you don't have a generic function here.

Comment: @zerkms: item[field] is not always a number, therefore I need to restrict field param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type to restrict the property value of `field` to numbers only like this:

```
function sum<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends string>(source: T[], field: K) {
   let sum = 0
   for(const item of source) {
       const s = item[field] // Record<K, number>[K], canonical number
       sum = sum + s
   }
   return sum
}
```

Test it:

```
sum([{foo: "adsf", myField: 3}, {myField: 10}], "myField") // OK, sum: 13
sum([{myField: 3}, {myField: "duuhh"}], "myField") // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwDwBVEFMAeUuYAJsogEq4RwBOJGA0gDSJjoBGutAfK43kLEyKKLRhgA5jwAUyOCFoRcALkRYA2gF1WwGLgA2JNYwCUiAN4AoRLYO4oKdIgC8iAAw3bwOjJphkRxgiNEQ4YBQFJVxza1t4239AlFdEYNw0DT1DEi1EAHp8ymo6BhY2Tm4eDUYdRAgAQzAEGEaDCrQuWi8Ep1C3VFCAahQegF8e2gdFJEGrCasrQZkNCx84NQAiBrJgTdY0AE8AMX0jNQBmMdYLI9OctQBGdzG6zbuzkk3zQsQAeXKgyeFyW6BWtxOn0u10sHweiE2JBAIAAFijNq9WO9ITlvgUitxaHRFiSrEA)

Comment: `function sum<K extends string>(source: Array<Record<K, number>>, valueProperty: K)` work too

Comment: Sure, you can do that, depends on the use case! Then you can only pass in objects `T` that contain exactly one property `K`. The first test in the answer would fail, if `source` was `Array<Record<K, number>>` and not a generic type parameter extending the record.

Comment: In both cases I get error in the first parameter (`source`). Additionally, in both cases I don't get autocomplete for the field property, so I don't see the difference.
But I get the intellisense (and rename refactoring) with:
`function sum<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>`

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit? I need to restrict the parameter also in non generic function...

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what you are meaning. The second test from above just raises an error, because I passed in a `string` instead of `number`. Also, you should get autocomplete for the `source` object property, as soon as you specify the second function parameter - so set the 2nd parameter first, and then go over to `source`. If you don't specify the generic type parameter, the compiler expects exactly `Array<Record<K, number>>` for `source`. Otherwise it expects an extending parameter, so the object could have additional properties. Can you provide a playground illustrating your case?